# Serial Port Trigger DataReceived when certain amounts of bytes received

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to write a program that updates a windows form every time new data comes in on a serial port, but am struggling with understanding how the serial port works, and how I can use it in a way I want it.

I have an external device sending 8 bytes at 1Hz to my serial port, and wish to use the DataReceived event from the SerialPort Class. When I debug my code, the event is more or less triggered randomly based on what the program is doing at a certain time. The code as is is below:

```
    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //byte[] rxbyte = new byte[1];
        byte[] rxbyte = new byte[8];
        byte currentbyte;
        port.Read(rxbyte, 0, port.BytesToRead);

        currentbyte = rxbyte[0];

        int channel = (currentbyte >> 6) & 3; //3 = binary 11, ANDS the last 2 bits
        int msb_2bit = (currentbyte >> 0) & 255; //AND compare all bits in a byte
        currentbyte = rxbyte[1];
        int val = ((msb_2bit << 8) | (currentbyte << 0));

        //Extra stuff

        SetText_tmp1(val.ToString());
    }
```

I want to be able to have exactly 8 bytes in the receive buffer before I call the Read function, but I am not sure how to do this (never used SerialPort class before), and want to do all manipulation of data only when I have the entire 8 bytes. Is there a built in way to toggle the event only when a certain amount of bytes are in the buffer? Or is there another way to obtain only 8 bytes, but not more, and leave the remaining bytes to the next instance?

Comment: Apparently you have an XY problem.  You got an answer for problem Y, but IMO you still have to solve X.  If this is just homework, then a robust solution is probably not necessary (but should be worth an A or extra credit).  If this is for a real product, then you're not done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you are not coding this correctly.  You cannot predict how many bytes you are going to receive.  So just don't process the received bytes until you've got them all.  Like this:

```
private byte[] rxbyte = new byte[8];
private int rxcount = 0;

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    rxcount += port.Read(rxbyte, rxcount, 8 - rxcount);
    if (rxcount < 8) return;
    rxcount = 0;
    // Process rxbyte content
    //...
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this code will "work" most of the time, but is not robust enough to work all the time.  There's no logic for message synchronization.

Comment: How do you expect me to add that from the info in the question?  He was asking for a way where he'll never get that to work, at least he's got a shot at it with this code.

Comment: The probability that the routine starts reading during the silence rather than during a message is proportional to the baud rate and intercharacter spacing (typically or near zero on modern systems).  As the baud rate gets faster, the probability increases that the message synchronization is correct. *"How do you expect me ..."* -- I didn't write that you had to provide a complete solution, but you didn't mention message frame synchronization at all, which is an implied requirement of the proper solution.

Comment: For my purpose, it was simply getting the serial communication to work in a way I want it to so I could test other parts of my code. I know that the best way is to have packet structuring information inside the packet with headers, and receive until the header says your done, but just needed a quick way to get this going to test other stuff. Another way would be to have timeouts for a 1hz transmission of 8 bytes, as I know the data is sent back to back in pulses, but I figure it would be more difficult to figure out timers than to use a quick dirty method of getting exactly 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ReceivedBytesThreshold property to 8. As in `port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 8;`

Comment: This is too simplistic to properly achieve synchronization on message frames.  You need to guarantee that the count starts on the first byte of the message.

Comment: If you follow Hans's answer this is not needed.

Comment: @sawdust - yes, it is simplistic and arguably wrong based on the rest of the code provided. However, the post only states "I want to be able to have exactly 8 bytes in the receive buffer before I call the Read function". Nothing about synchronization is included, though almost certainly necessary.

Comment: @dbasnett - Hans' answer does exactly the same thing, only manually.

Answer (score 0):

An effective way to handle this is to add a timer to the class that ticks along at maybe 9 times a second. Eliminate the serial port event handler completely.

At each timer tick have the code check the serial port for bytes received from the serial port. If there are some there then grab them out of the serial port and append them to the end of buffer maintained in the class as a data member.

When the buffer has eight or more characters in it then timer tick logic would take the first 8 bytes out of the buffer and use them to update the user interface window. Any remaining bytes in the buffer can be moved up to the head of the buffer.

The timer tick routine can also maintain a counter value that increments each time the tick comes in and there is no data ready at the serial port at this tick. When this counter reaches a value of say 3 or 4 the code would reset the data buffer to empty and reset the counter back to zero. When data is actually seen from the serial port this counter is reset to zero. The purpose of this counter mechanism is to synchronize the data receive buffer with the 1Hz data stream coming in so the receive process does not get out of sync with what data represents the start of the 8-byte message.

Note that this method is superior to the serial port received data event because it allows your program to stay in control of things. I've already described the ability to synchronize with the data stream bursts - which is not possible to do with trying to set the serial port received data threshold to a count like 8. Another advantage is that the timer tick code can include additional handling functions such as signalling a timeout if no data arrives from the serial port in say 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: @sawdust - The timer itself is event driven. As a consequence of repeated events the timeout is measured. I can say from having built many apps that use serial port that this scheme works very well. Maybe the quoted comment is too strong for everyone but it has served well for my applications that are used in dozens of industrial production environments.

Comment: *"Note that this method is superior ..."* -- Not really, you are suggesting that polling is "better" than event driven.  If the latency is tolerable, then it's a possible solution.  I don't know C# at all, but in C I think non-canonical reads using appropriate VMIN and VTIME settings would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - why would you fire a timer 9 times per second for data that arrives @ 1 byte/sec?  I like Hans's answer.  The problem with avoiding the handler is that the timer has to do the read AND process the data which works for low bit rates, but not so good for higher rates.

Comment: @dbasnett - I was working within the parameters given by the OP. He says his 8-byte bundles of data arrive once per second. Since he apparently does not have his data content bounded with framing information one must use timing to judge the data boundaries. This maybe could be done with 4-5 ticks per second but long ago I noted that at 9 or greater ticks per second the user will generally not notice latency variation in the user interface update. At slower rates they will. As far as where the data is read and processed - it makes no difference where this is done if this is a (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) task required of the computer. Event handlers are not interrupt service routines. If the data must be gathered and displayed who cares where it gets spread out in the available bandwidth available in the processing of all events in system. Of course where ever it is done you need to make the work short and sweet so other things like mouse and touch do not suffer. If the data handling does get complex and takes a long time it can easily be split up and handled across multiple timer ticks. I do that kind of thing in my production applications all the time.

Comment: I stand corrected on the rate stated by the OP.  You stated, "Note that this method is superior ...", and that simply isn't true for all situations.  At very high data rates (noted that isn't the case here) it just won't work.  If you use the event handler you know exactly when your criteria is met, and the UI control flow is only interrupted then.  For this question your suggestion is OK.

Comment: @dbasnett - High data rates were not the discussion here but non the less I agree that if one were working with data at full pipe bandwidth at high baud rate there would have to be other considerations made in design. If you depend solely on the Serial Port received data event handler then it behooves the designer to craft the data flow protocol with discrete markers to define the framing. Without framing there is loss of synchronization capability if you rely solely on the received event handler.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - using the handler works just fine with counts and mechanisms can be built in that can check for data exhaustion.  I agree that many serial devices have poor data protocols.

Comment: *"Without framing there is loss of synchronization ..."*  -- the message framing appears to be temporal.  I'm assuming that the baud rate is reasonable (e.g. >9600 baud), so that there would be a relatively long time interval before the next message arrives about a second later.  Modbus is an established protocol that uses timing (rather than data as *"discrete markers"*) to establish framing.  Some UARTs have a timer to detect non-activity on the RxD input to support such protocols.